# What is the meaning of a quote in the conversion specification of a format string?

Tags: c, format-specifiers

I discovered we can use one (or multiple) quote in the conversion specification of a format string. For instance:

```
void f(int i)
{
    printf("%'d\n", i);
}
```

This code compiles well and behaves exactly as without the quote.

I would like to know what is the meaning of this quote. Does it can have an effect on the behavior of the `printf` function? If not, why is this allowed?

I found no information about it in [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cppreference documents the C standard. The apostrophe is an extension to the C standard documented by POSIX. From [POSIX fprintf](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html):

> The flag characters and their meanings are:
>
> '
> (The <apostrophe>.) The integer portion of the result of a decimal conversion ( %i, %d, %u, %f, %F, %g, or %G ) shall be formatted with thousands' grouping characters. For other conversions the behavior is undefined. The non-monetary grouping character is used.

Answer (score 0):

This is documented -
Puts in commas for integers

eg

```
1,000
```

not

```
1000
```

If your locality uses 3 digits between commas

> c.f. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string

Comment: That Wikipedia page is not a good source. It fails to state the apostrophe flag is defined by POSIX and not by the C standard. As does this answer.

Comment: Not quite sure what you take issue with @EricPostpischil -- the page I referenced includes links to posix standards.    Please feel free to edit my answer if it can be made better.

Comment: The page does have links to POSIX standard. But it does not state that the apostrophe flag is defined by POSIX and not by the C standard. And neither does this answer.

Comment: It links to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_UNIX_Specification which seems to discuss POSIX in depth

Comment: The table entry for the apostrophe flag says “The integer or exponent of a decimal has the thousands grouping separator applied.” That sentence does not say whether or not the flag is defined by the POSIX standard. That sentence does not say whether or not the flag is defined by the C standard. It lacks information. A reader would not know, from that table, whether they can rely on a program written for a C implementation, but not a POSIX implementation, would work with an apostrophe flag. The fact the information might be in some huge linked resource does not remedy this deficiency.

Comment: Further, the information is not in the linked resource. The POSIX documentation documents what the apostrophe does in POSIX. It does not state that this is a POSIX extension and is not defined by the C standard.